# Who's on my Marvel coffee mug?

Tags: marvel, character-identification

I got a new mug recently and people *will not stop asking who is on it*.

I can name the first few rows (mostly) but after that I'm really struggling.

I can't find any other images online either, largely because there's so many Marvel mugs.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcFHG.jpg) is the album of photos I took of it, and a sample:

[image: Left side of the mug in question]

Comment: This jigsaw looks like it might be a cropped version of the image on your mug: http://www.amazon.com/Marvel-Heroes-piece-R-1000-605-japan/dp/B008RXBWDG And there are much larger versions floating around online – but I can’t find another image as wide as the mug.

Comment: “people will not stop asking who is on it” — People. What a bunch of b—rds.

Comment: Also, is the floating head from [Zardoz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zardoz) for some reason?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite I think it's [ego](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ego_the_Living_Planet) the living planet.

Comment: @AncientSwordRage: ah yes, that would make more sense.

Comment: http://thekoalition.com/images/2015/05/Marvel-Universe.jpg

Comment: I'm reasonably sure that the guy in red with the DD symbol on his chest is 'The Flash'.

Comment: So many superheroes and they leave off Superman? What a crappy mug

Comment: FF and X-Men still in there - http://www.comicbookmovie.com/comics/marvel_comics/uh-oh-the-x-men-and-fantastic-4-are-not-featured-on-marvels-a121188

Comment: I don’t recognise a single character in the photo in the question here. Does that make me an SFF pariah?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - Yes. Hang your head in shame and go read something that isn't Harry Potter; http://www.wired.com/2012/03/an-intro-to-marvel-for-newbies/

Comment: These pictures aren't quite detailed enough for some of the characters, and online versions are similarly lacking detail :(

Comment: @CreationEdge I was worried that might be the case. I was going someone with better google Fu could help find the original.

Comment: When I get home I might photoshop all the pics into one or something. Hmmm

Comment: @RedCaio I tried, it wasn't helpful.

Comment: Well, I found similar photos, but I spent a crazy amount of time trying to track down the original. No luck. They just reuse the art for different arrangements, and it's not attributed to any one artist (or timeframe, really). Based on the characters, I think  it might be a 2009 edition, but the others I found already existed then, too, so that didn't help.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Left-to-right

### Top Row

- Galactus
- Silver Surfer (riding in front of Galactus)
- Stature (Cassandra Lang)
- Ego the Living Planet
- Black Bolt:
  [image]  [image]
- Fin Fang Foom (Dragon)
- Living Tribunal
- Vision
- Nova
- Red cape, large red helmet with horns
- Ice Man (previously thought this was Silver Surfer, but I was wrong)
- Not Deathbird.
- ?? Black Cape, maybe white hair. Possibly Storm.
- Possibly Wonder Man
- Banshee
- Firestorm (possibly Human Torch)
- Unclear. Giant guy, maybe purple.
- Vulture
- Green Goblin
- Atlas
- These 4 Celestials from a Dr. Doom "What If" story:
  [image]
- A Sentinel (far right)
- Angel (This costume):
  [image]
- Snowbird:
  [image]

### Front Row

- Doctor Strange
- Colossus
- Beast
- Sabertooth
- Doctor Doom
- Daredevil
- Magneto
- Cyclops
- Invisible Woman/Mrs. Fantastic
- Captain Mar-vell (star on chest)
- She-Hulk
- Iron Man
- Wolverine
- Captain America
- Ant-Man:
  [image]
- Hulk
- Thor
- Spider-man
- Hawkeye
- Thing
- Mr. Fantastic
- The Leader (Big green head)
- Havok (Starjammers edition)
  [image]
- Abomination
- Elektra
- Black Cat
- Iron Fist
- The Punisher
- Possibly Ms. Marvel (Carol Danvers) above Punisher

### Second Row

- Face in shadows [placeholder]
- Guy with stretchy neck. Not Plastic Man or Elongated Man (wrong hair color for both)
- Black monster guy with white blue hair [placeholder]
- Guy with white hair [placeholder]
- Black guy
- Thanos
- Mystique
- Moon Knight
- Rhino (cross-referenced from other pics):
  [image]
- Possibly Luke Cage
- Black Widow
- Guy with black eye mask [placeholder]
- Falcon?
- This guy:
  [image]
- Black face guy [playceholder]
- Red Skull
- Kang the Conquerer. Alt pic:
  [image]
- White haired, white female, not Black Cat. No mask.
- Possibly venom
- Female, black hair, red mask, red armband/paint, not Scarlet Witch
- White/blue skinned, black costume with yellow chest, red X or symbol on chest. Possibly alt costume:
  [image]
- Scarlet Witch (right of Thing)
- Enchantress (Polaris should have green hair)

### Misc

- Medusa (giant red hair in back row)
- Swamp Thing (next to Medusa)
- Holocaust (beneath Nova):
  [image]
- Maestro (Green face to left of guy fist pumping (that's to the left of the other guy fist pumping) in back row)
- Scorpion (below Green Goblin):
  [image]  [image]
- Loki (far left, by Sentinel leg):
  [image]
- Doc Ock (front of Sentinel):
  [image]
- Chameleon (ruled out Morph and White Skull based on having black around neck):
  [image] [image]
- Hela (above Mar-vell's head):
  [image]
- Most likely Dormammu, due to proximity to Dr. Strange:
  [image]
- J. Jonah Jameson (top left of Scarlet Witch's headpiece):
  [image]
- Morph (based on having yellow and blue costume and no real discernible nose. Also, in one of the other images another version of Morph is in roughly the same place, which is very common in these pics):
  [image]
- Silver Samurai (based on image I found in similar picture, which shows more. Notice red star design on chest. 3rd pic is more common, where you see his sword):
  [image]  [image]  [image]
- Strong suspicion this is Hellcat (Pointy ears, red hair, black mask, yellow below):
  [image]
- Super-Skrull (2nd pic from another image):
  [image]  [image]
- Academy X's Surge (blue hair) and Elixir (gold skin) (Second pic for verification shows additional members of same team: Prodigy, Wind Dancer, Surge, Wallflower, Elixir):
  [image] [image]
- Captain Britain (easier to tell in 2nd pic):
  [image]  [image]

---

I was unable to find this exact image in a decent size for reproduction. A cropped version has been used for a puzzle and some other merchandise, but nothing large-scale, either.

Many similar images exist, with slightly different arrangements and different version of the characters. Here's what I found (Image search them for more variants):

Exact (I think) image:
[image]

Cropped version:
[image]

Others (After clicking the thumbnail, you can get full-resolution by deleting the "m" from the end of the filename):
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I've edited in the highest resolution version I can find.

Comment: Purple, green, and blue dude is Kang the Conqueror. http://marvel.com/universe/Kang

Comment: @Joe Perfect! I hoped the close up would help. Looks like the some pic in higher resolution!

Comment: That's quite incredible!

Comment: @AncientSwordRage I've found a bunch more, and changed a couple after getting better images. I could probably find even more if you could provide some more pics. (Have camera flat on table, rotate cup around. Also try doing it with cup upside down to get better detail of small heads.)

Comment: In the 2nd Row, "This Guy" might be Warpath

Comment: "Second row: White/blue skinned, black costume with yellow chest, red X or symbol on chest. Possibly alt costume" - Dead Girl
"Female, black hair, red mask, red armband/paint, not Scarlet Witch: - Jessica Drew/Spider-Woman?
"White haired, white female, not Black Cat. No mask." - Silver Sable?

Comment: @Dre Absolutely Dead Girl, thanks! I couldn't find that version of Spider-woman's costume, but that's my guess.  Let me check on Sable.

Comment: @CreationEdge I'm thinking it might be Spider Woman's [classic red costume](http://www.marveldirectory.com/pictures/individuals/s_1d/spiderwomani.jpg), not the more recent version. I might be looking at a different part of the image; I'm talking about the character behind Spidey's left knee.
That's definitely [Kingpin](https://40.media.tumblr.com/8c0f78398b2969714c664650480bafb3/tumblr_nmptbhhw6h1rvm4udo1_500.jpg) just behind the Thing, as drawn by John Romita JR.